# Non-blocking close - How to ensure data got send?

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send buffer empty of Socket in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476907/send-buffer-empty-of-socket-in-linux)

I want to create a socket server sending some data to a connecting client and disconnect him again.

I'm using non-blocking sockets so I don't know how to figure out if all data have at least been sent (send?) correctly (in short: no more data in my send buffer).
I don't want to keep the connection established if it's not neccessary anymore because I can't ensure that the client disconnects on his own.

Currently I'm just shutting down the client using shutdown() and later close(). But testing showed me a client does not always recieve all data before the connection gets closed.

There must be a way to ensure all data got send before closing the connection on non-blocking sockets, too, isn't there? Hope my question is clear enough and you can help me (:

Comment: I'm developing using C++, but I'm using the glibc sockets.

Comment: Hadn't we had that before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12476907/694576

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can know your data has been sent prior to ending the connection is for the peer to acknowledge it in the application protocol. You can ensure that both ends get to EOS at the same time by shutting down for output at both ends and then reading to EOS at both ends, then closing the socket at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

you can send the file size prior to data of the file. While closing the socket just check the file size and take appropriate action to close or resend the file....